# QGIS 2.2 Crash dumped on Windows 8.1

Tags: qgis, windows-8

After I installed QGIS 2.2 via OSGeo4W, as I click the icon of QGIS, then it shows this up,

[image]

so I can't open QGIS 2.2

Here's some look like troublesome lines in my installation log,

```
2014/03/23 13:42:15 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such     file or directory
2014/03/23 13:42:15 Current Directory: C:\Users\Heinz\Installation files
2014/03/23 13:42:15 Root Directory: C:\OSGeo4W64
2014/03/23 13:42:15 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2014/03/23 13:42:17 root: C:\OSGeo4W64
2014/03/23 13:42:17 Selected local directory: C:\Users\Heinz\Installation files
2014/03/23 13:42:17 Menu name: OSGeo4W
2014/03/23 13:42:17 net: Direct
2014/03/23 13:42:19 site: http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
2014/03/23 13:42:19 mbox note: Unable to get setup.ini from <http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/>
2014/03/23 13:43:00 site: http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
2014/03/23 13:43:00 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2014/03/23 13:43:01 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/timestamp) failed 2 No such file or directory
```

How to fix this problem？

I am working under Windows 8.1 64-bit

---

**Update#1**
I follow the suggestion of the answer in the post, [How to debug QGIS installation problems on XP?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34533/how-to-debug-qgis-installation-problems-on-xp?rq=1), download Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable and then install qgis 2.2 using OSGeo4W package, and here's the same part of the installation log,

```
2014/03/23 16:17:39 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2014/03/23 16:17:39 Current Directory: C:\Users\Heinz\Installation files
2014/03/23 16:17:39 Root Directory: C:\OSGeo4W64
2014/03/23 16:17:39 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2014/03/23 16:17:40 root: C:\OSGeo4W64
2014/03/23 16:17:40 Selected local directory: C:\Users\Heinz\Installation files
2014/03/23 16:17:40 Menu name: OSGeo4W
2014/03/23 16:17:40 net: Direct
2014/03/23 16:17:43 site: http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
2014/03/23 16:17:43 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2014/03/23 16:17:43 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/timestamp) failed 2 No such file or directory
```

I can successfully launch Qgis browser, but I still have the same dumped message that I can't launch qgis desktop.

---

**Update#2**
I have uninstalled the 64-bit version and installed the 32-bit OSGeo4W package. I have checked the installation log, just like the one I post in **Update#1**, and the rest part of it is fine.

I still got the same error message, but unlike the 64-bit version message, the same mbox would appear after I click the confirm button, this time I just have to click **confirm** in the mbox one time. And I can still launch qgis browser.

**Are there someone successfully launching qgis 2.2 on windows 8.1 x64 computer？**

Comment: QGIS is crashing. Perhaps you wanted to file a bug report on the QGIS site?

Comment: the same error occurred after I installed the standalone version(both 32 and 64-bit)

Comment: @BradHards excuse me, what do you mean?

Comment: If you have a bug, you need to tell the authors. https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Bugreports

Comment: Hace a closer look at C:\OSGEo4W\var\log\setup.log.full for any error emssages.

Comment: @AndreJoost I have added the log in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the mbox note, I get the same messages, so these are not critical. Problems may arise later on.

I suggest to uninstall all installed standalone versions, erase the C:\OSGeo4W64 folder and the C:\users\Heinz.qgis2 folder, and make a clean install with the 32bit version into C:\OSGeo4W.

I'm not sure if there are any Windows 8.1 related blockers, current versions (32bit and 64bit) definitely run on Windows 7 64bit.

If the rest of the installation log does not give any hints, a bug report including dump and log files can adress the problem to the developers (who do not read here).

Comment: although the same message, in my case I can't launch it.…and you mean install OSGeo4W 32 bit version on 64 bit computer?

Comment: Yes, up to QGIS 1.8 we had only 32 bit, and the first 64bit versions had severe issues. That's why I still work with the 32 bit version. Make sure you have full rights on C:\OSGeo4W\. Have you looked through the rest of the log file?

Comment: thank you, and I have edited my post. Although I still got the same mbox, I think if regedit matter because I used to delete qgis-related file via regedit command, but after that, I have installed and uninstalled qgis many times.

Comment: I tried to run it as administrator, and it worked! No more error mbox!

Comment: Ok, I have always full admin rights, so I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same issue - QGIS 2.2 64bit did not start at all on my Windows 8.1 system. I uninstalled QGIS and Visual C++ 2010 (both 32bit and 64bit) that QGIS had installed, and then I installed Visual C++ 2012 64bit from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679. Afterwards I installed QGIS 2.2. 64bit again. It finally works (both when I run it as an admin, and as a regular user).

Another (better?) solution: I changed my user folder name and reinstalled QGIS, making sure that there are no diacritic signs and empty spaces in file paths (e.g., 'Pawel' instead of 'Paweł' in my user folder, 'd:/programs' instead of 'c:/program files', and 'QGIS_Valmiera' instead of 'QGIS Valmiera'). It fixed a number of problems with Python-based plug-ins. I'm finally able to use GRASS and the Open Layers plug-in.

Comment: @Pawei Kranzberg Have you start QGIS as an administrator at the very beginning?

Comment: No. But one more thing - my QGIS is on c: partition, I couldn't get it to work on d: . It might be connected with GRASS - when installed on c: the GRASS icon on the desktop is OK, but when on d: there is only 'placeholder' GRASS icon on my desktop.

Comment: So you mean you want to install it under D directory?

Comment: I wanted to install it on my second disk partition, instead of the one with the OS on it.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not  programmer or anything, but what worked for me was turning off the firewall. It appears that the incoming data for the gps (bluetooth in my case) are received as threats.